# Google Site Optimizer not tracking cross-domain conversions

Tags: google-analytics, google-website-optimizer, multivariate-testing

I've set up three GWO multivariate tests across two domains. I've got the landing page set up correctly, and it's tracking visitors for all three tests, but conversions aren't being recorded for any of them. I've followed the instructions Google provides for [cross-domain tracking](http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151978), but still no dice.

Here's the landing page snippet (IDs removed):

```html
<script>
    // Allows for multiple-domain tracking
    _udn = "none";
</script>
<!-- Google Website Optimizer Control Script -->
<script>
    function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}
    (function(){var k='xxxxxxxxxx',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;function f(n){
    if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.
    length+1,j<0?c.length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;
    d.write('<sc'+'ript src="'+
    'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':'://www')+'.google-analytics.com'
    +'/siteopt.js?v=1&utmxkey='+k+'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='
    +new Date().valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
    '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></sc'+'ript>')})();
</script>
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Control Script -->
<!-- Google Website Optimizer Tracking Script -->
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setAllowLinker', 'true']);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/xxxxxxxxxx/test']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Tracking Script -->
```

And here's the conversion page snippet:

```html
<!-- Google Website Optimizer Conversion Script -->
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/xxxxxxxxxx/goal']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- end of Google Website Optimizer Conversion Script -->
```

A few gotchas:

- The conversion script snippet is in the footer, before the closing `</body>` tag. This is due to the way the site is built.
- The URL of the conversion page is variable, depending on how a visitor proceeds through the funnel that precedes it.
- Both the landing page & the conversion page have the Google Analytics snippet inserted after the GWO snippet (though in one case, there is no Analytics snippet on the conversion page).

Comment: And, as it turns out, I missed step 4 on http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151978. So, please make sure to always follow all the steps…

Comment: Or, y'know, still not working, even with that step 4 set up correctly. Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the code of the `siteopt.js` code GWO loads to assign test combinations to users, it seems the `_udn` variable doesn't support `'none'`, but only the *actual* value the cookie domain should be scoped to. Try setting it to whatever the domain used by the page that has the GWO code on it instead (i e `'my.domain.com'` instead of `'none'`).

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Google's own instructions state to use the value of `none`.

Answer (score 0):

In your landing page snippet you have: 
`_gaq.push(['gwo._setAllowLinker', 'true']);`

If you take a look at Google documentation you will find out that the correct way to enable the linker is: 
`_gaq.push(['gwo._setAllowLinker', true]); // TRUE is not eclosed in apostrophes`

Hope this helps.